# How to enable SSL in JaxWsProxyFactoryBean?

Tags: java, ssl, cxf, jax-ws, webclient

So I want to enable SSL support in JaxWsProxyFactoryBean object but could not find any resource for the same.

Comment: You can find solution example here: https://www.javafixing.com/2022/04/fixed-apache-cxf-jaxwsproxyfactorybean.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.